# Организация файлов для создания установочного файла Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имеется решение sln, состоящее из двух частей(в одном решении два проекта). В одной из частей имеется работа с файлом. Этот файл находится в отдельной папке(предположим, images). Как правильно указать относительный путь к файлу, при условии, что в дальнейшем планируется создание установочного файла(т.е. не Debug версия)? На данный момент иерархия следующая:

```
-Project
  -Debug
     -images
       -image.png
  -Project1
    -some files
  -Project2
    -project2.cpp
    -some other files
  -.sln and other files
```

И в project2.cpp указан относительный путь к файлу как "images/image.png"

Comment: может быть лучше разместить файл в домашней папке пользователя, если вы не знаете точно где будет ваш исполняемый файл...

Comment: Используйте абсолютный путь, получая его относительно пути к исполняемому файлу.

Comment: @user7860670 Можете уточнить, что вы имеете в виду. Можно в виде гайда на ресурсе